# Eclipse: 'System' cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

First i installed java 7.0 update 25 and then installed eclipse.
Later as per requirement, I uninstalled this java version and installed earlier version 5.0

Now in every eclipse program, it is showing error with word 'System'.
Solution is to add path of java.exe to eclipse.
Can anyone guide me to do it?

Comment: Open Window > Preferences. Type 'jre' into search box. Add your Java installation directory to the installed JRE's.

Comment: Eclipse is probably still configured to use JDK 7 instead of 5. Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.

Answer (score 13):

To resolve this problem perform below steps:
Go to Package Explorer -> Select your Project -> Right click on your project -> go to Properties-> Click on Java build path -> select your JRE file (mostly it will display error) and click on edit button which is on right side -> new dialog box will get displayed as “JRE System Library” in this window select radio button i.e"Workspace default JRE(jre6)" or whichever you have installed. 
Then click on finish.
Errors will not come.

Comment: For me, I had to delete the JRE from my build path completely and re-add it to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

The solution to the above problem is, change the JRE system library by doing the following:

1. Right click on your project and select properties.
2. Select Libraries from the tab.
3. Select the current JRE system library and click on edit.
4. Select either Alternate JRE or Workspace default JRE (Latest version of JRE).
5. Click Finish and then OK.

Answer (score 2):

On Eclipse Oxygen, follow steps from (1) to (6) shown below figure.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For those who make errors as I do, check whether the error is  "'**S**ystem' cannot be resolved" or "'**s**ystem' cannot be resolved."  In the latter case, capitalizing system will likely cure the problem.  In the former case, follow directions above.  Only wasted an hour figuring that one out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem a little bit different. That may be because on my computer "java" doesn't work at Windows/cmd.exe because it is not listed in the Windows-PATH variable.

My solution is this:

1. `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries`
2. `Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Alternate JRE -> Installed JREs…`
3. `Dialog “Installed JREs” open -> [Add…] -> “Standard VM”`
4. `Dialog “JRE Definition” opens -> JRE home: [Directory…]`
5. Select the path to your JRE.

Use `[Finish]` or `[Apply]` several time. I hope it also works for you.