# JasperException JBWEB004062 Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, java-8, jboss7.x, java-17

I'm currently migrating my app from JBoss **7.3** to **7.4.1**, and Java **8** to **17**.

The app starts apparently ok, but in some jsp file are throwing a `JasperException : System cannot be resolved`.

This is what the log shows when the error occurs:

```
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP: #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) JBWEB004060: An error occurred at line: 469 in the jsp file: /someFile.jsp #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) System cannot be resolved #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 466: var months = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]; #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 467: var myVar = window.setInterval(function(){ setTimerHeader() }, 60000); #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 468: var jsVar = <%=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()%>; #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,903 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 469: var timeZoneOffset =<%=java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())%>; #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,904 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 470: jsVar = jsVar; #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,904 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 471: #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,904 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 472: var hours = ""; #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,905 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Stacktrace: #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,905 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:95) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,905 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:455) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:359) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:652) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:262) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToServlet(ServletInitialHandler.java:197) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.includeImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:391) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.setupIncludeImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:326) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:290) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:907) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.apache.jsp.inicio_jsp._jspx_meth_logic_005fpresent_005f0(inicio_jsp.java:187) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.apache.jsp.inicio_jsp._jspService(inicio_jsp.java:116) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,907 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at deployment.regional.war//com.elektra.regional.web.filters.AutenticationFilter.doFilter(AutenticationFilter.java:288) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.jsp@2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:280) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,909 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.1.GA-redhat-00003//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:260) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.9.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,911 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,911 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,911 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final-redhat-00001//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280) #]
[# 2023-02-27 13:57:48,911 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) #]
```

I'm working with Eclipse, I restarted it and reconfigured Java JDK in the Build Path, but without success.

I also tried to import the `java.lang.System` class in the jsp file, but it keeps throwing `JasperExcepction`.

Comment: Did you try top solution? at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467397/eclipse-system-cannot-be-resolved